# zipWith Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have created this data type and function:

```
type Bit = Int

randomFloatList :: Int -> [Float]
randomFloatList seed = randoms (mkStdGen seed)
```

And I want to create a function that uses `zipWith`. The function has a `seed` as an argument that is used to the `randomFloatList`, if the random element is between 0 and noise then the bit is changed. I am trying to do it this way, but I am with difficulties with `zipWith`:

Thanks.

Comment: What difficulties are we talking about? Provide some more code to allow us to determine what fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want to take a list of `Bit`s and use a random list to decide whether to alter the original. (If not, please clarify.)

```
channel :: Int -> Float -> [Bit] -> [Bit]
channel seed noise xs = zipWith (alterBit noise) (randomFloatList seed) xs
```

Notice you didn't need some of the brackets - you don't need brackets for function application, just for grouping.

```
alterBit :: Float -> Float -> Bit -> Bit
alterBit noise random bit | random <= noise = alter bit
                          | otherwise = bit
```

Again, I've removed any reference to the list that I'm using this with - `zipWith` will send this function the *single* elements it needs out of the list of floats and bits.

I took the liberty of defining

```
data Bit = O | I deriving Show
```

and could only think of one alter function:

```
alter :: Bit -> Bit
alter O = I
alter I = O
```

Let's test it:

```
> take 6 $ randomFloatList 3
[0.10321328,0.98988104,0.46191382,0.8553592,0.7980472,0.35561606]

> map (<= 0.5) $ take 6 $ randomFloatList 3
[True,False,True,False,False,True]

> channel 3 0.5 [O,O,O,O,O,O]
[I,O,I,O,O,I]
```

Yup, that changed the ones it should.

Answer (score 0):

`zipWith`'s signature is `(a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`. That means that it is useful for mapping a function that takes two arguments over two lists.

I think, in your case you just want to map a function over a single list (because your function `alterBit` only takes one argument), so you'd have to use `map`, not `zipWith`.

Note also that `seed` and `noise` won't be visible by `alterBit` unless you define them as constants in your module or pass them explicitly to `alterBit`.

Comment: I get to the correct solution. Thanks for your explain, it was helpfull.